# My WebView does not finish loading

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi I have totally no idea why my webview is not call the onPageFinished method, and the it was showing the loading dialog all the time, I hope there is someone out there help me for my this issue. In the Android manifest file I already put the internet permission and also the network access state.

so this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    RelativeLayout rLoading;
    Map<String, String> header;

    String urlToLoad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        rLoading = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loading);

        if ( isNetworkAvailable() == true )     //check if internet available or not
        {
            mWebView.setFocusable(true);
            mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

            urlToLoad = "https://www.google.com/";

            UsernamePasswordCredentials creds= new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
            Header credHeader = BasicScheme.authenticate(creds, "UTF-8", true);
            header = new HashMap<String, String>();
            header.put(credHeader.getName(), credHeader.getValue());
            //show loading dialog
            mWebView.loadUrl(urlToLoad, header);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                        rLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });
        }
        else    //Not connected
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "No internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        /// if no network is available networkInfo will be null
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
  }
```

Someone please help me

Comment: did your page loading completed? What i mean are u able to see the page loaded on the screen?

Comment: man, I stop using java but, in your `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){...});` call, try to verify if the current page showed is the -1 page, anything like `if (view.amethodtogetpageindex == -1) ...;`
we are migrating all our apps to c# cross platform, but java is fresh in my mind already

Comment: The webpage come out in physical device but not in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try this Android WebView implementation:

```
        webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               //stop the ProgressBar
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way

```
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {

            //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```